# Having trouble running Chrome App in Genymotion Emulator with Google Play installed

Tags: android, google-chrome, genymotion

I am trying to use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download) to run Android 5.0 (android version does not matter here as it fails for multiple). I installed Google Play ([from here](https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145)). All other apps work (and Chrome used to also) but I guess they made some update and now whenever I click on Chrome, the app crashes (screenshot below).

I am just looking for ANY solution that allows me to run Chrome app in Genymotion. Is there a way to get just the APK for Chrome to install in the Emulator? (Dont want to do native emulator as it is sooooooo slooowwwww)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the newer versions of Chrome, so you can install an older version and it will work.

So first make sure that you uninstall the current Chrome version, and go to Google Play settings and TURN OFF the auto-update feature.

Then download this chrome version:
http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/chrome-44-0-2403-133-240313311-x86-android-apk-download/

Drag it into the emulator and it will auto install it. That should work.

If you get an error like "INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS", that means you need another version of Chrome, so go to www.apkmirror.com and look for your corresponding version of chrome. I've tried with the version from August 1 and it works.

Comment: Notice that link I gave you requires Android 5.0 as minimum version to work.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. For anyone else having this issue, this APK worked for me on Android 4.4.4: http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/chrome-40-0-2214-109-x86-android-apk-download/

Comment: you are welcome, I suppose at some point we will be able to use updated versions of chrome again.