# How to run latest Chrome builds in Genymotion

Tags: android, google-chrome, selenium, genymotion

I successfully added GApps and ARM support to my Genymotion v-2.5.2 using

How To Add Google Apps and ARM Support to Genymotion v2.0+

Original Source:[How do you install Google frameworks (Play, Accounts, etc.) on a Genymotion virtual device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt/20013322#20013322)

Play store works fine and i am able to download and install the latest versions of apps on to my virtual device. 
But when i launch chorme browser (v 46.0.2490.76), it crashes. It launches the browser for some seconds then crashes and gives a popup message "Unfortunately, Chrome has stopped"
I tried degrading the version to v 44 but still got the same result. [screenshot of the error on virtual device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic3iD.jpg)

virtual device details: Google Nexus 9-5.1.0-API22

Comment: This worked for me -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094217/having-trouble-running-chrome-app-in-genymotion-emulator-with-google-play-instal